# Getting Data from API (ok 200 Response Undefined Method 'id')

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

I got the below to work and call up membership data based on current_user.id (See 200 Ok response) this shows up in my logs.

```
GET https://api-e1.authrocket.com/v1/memberships?user_id=usr_0vKhXTr0K1bz6kUipKNnjD
-> 200 (103.4 ms)
NoMethodError (undefined method `id' for #<NCore::Collection:0x007f50c82a7e50>):app/controllers/directory/categories_controller.rb:13:in `index'
```

I was using current_user.id which worked.

```
@directory_category.user_id = current_user.id
```

Trying to change it so it grabs the user's membership.id

```
@directory_category.user_id = membership_info.id
```

The full create statement I'm working with.

```
# Create
def create
    @directory_category = Directory::Category.new(directory_category_params)
    @directory_category.user_id = membership_info.id
    if @directory_category.save
        redirect_to directory_categories_path, notice: 'Category was successfully created.'
        else
            render :new
    end
end

    # Directory Category Index
    def index
        @directory_categories = Directory::Category.where(user_id: membership_info.id)
    end
```

My attempt, which does say 200 ok getting current_user id and putting it at the end AuthRocket::Membership.all statement like below:

```
def current_user
    @_current_user ||= AuthRocket::Session.from_token(session[:ar_token]).try(:user)
end

def membership_info
    AuthRocket::Membership.all user_id: current_user.id
end
```

https://authrocket.com/docs/api/memberships

Comment: You trimmed out the most useful part of the error message `NoMethodError (undefined method 'id' for .......`  What comes after the dots?  I'm betting something with the word "Relation" in it.  The `all` method (assuming that's an ActiveRecord Model) returns a list of records.  Even if only one row in the DB matches, you still need to pick that item off of the list.

Comment: I just pasted rest of the error.

Comment: I had the right idea and the wrong word.  'Collection' indicates it's basically an array.  Your `membership_info` method is returning a list of rows.  Even if the size of the list is one row, you need to select that item.  Changing it to `AuthRocket::Membership.all(user_id: current_user.id).first` will probably fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your

```
def membership_info
    AuthRocket::Membership.all user_id: current_user.id
end
```

method is actually returning a collection and not a single item.  if you change it to

```
def membership_info
    AuthRocket::Membership.all(user_id: current_user.id).first
end
```

or whichever record you actually want, you should stop this error from raising.

Comment: Thanks I was a long way off of figuring it out.